# SwiftUI in macOS adding items to under the default "View" menu item

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

How do i add commands under the default "View" menu item in macOS?

eg. like in Finder

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add commands after the sidebar or tab commands like this:

```
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .sidebar) {
                Button("Test") {}
            }
        }
```